# Apex check for blank picklist value

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist

I am writing a trigger that has an IF clause based off of a field. However, I cannot get it to recognize if that picklist is blank. I have tried:

```
field.isblank()
string.isblank(field)
field == ''
field == '--None--'
field == NULL
```

None of these catch when there is no value. Prior to saving the record, the field says 'deleted' if I set it to --none--...but I'm not sure how to check that value within a trigger.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A picklist is essentially a string. For a string, you want to test using `isEmpty() == true`. That covers `''` and `null`. If you have a `--none--` you want to test against, you'll want to also add that specifically to your conditions if that's an optional value included in your picklist. If so, use a boolean `||`.

Comment: I tried "FIELD.ISEMPTY() == TRUE" and "isempty(FIELD) == TRUE" and neither seems to work...maybe something else in my code is weird...

Comment: Could very well be the case. It's difficult to say with only seeing the brief snippet and not having any more context.

Comment: Yep, I found it. I'm just feeling a bit stupid right now! I was editing my INSERT portion instead of my UPDATE portion. Thanks for the tips, I really appreciate your time!

Comment: I got the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isEmpty() from the type String" and used "if (myObject.myPickListField__c != null){...}"